# How to do book paragraph recognition with python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I know this might be a tough question to answer, but being new to image processing with Python I need some pointers.

This is what I have:

- A page of a school book, full of paragraphs and marginal notes

[Image of the original page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BoRI.jpg)

But this is what I have to do:

- Divide the page into paragraphs
- Save an image for each single paragraph

[Image of the final page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWvOp.jpg)

[Example of a cut paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGg3Z.jpg)

My question is if there are libraries that allow you to do this.

Comment: [Tessaract](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/) is an OCR program that can parse paragraphs. You can execute it in python with the package pytesseract.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pytesseract library. Here's a link for some documentation with examples [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)